# SharePoint 2013 - Content Rollup - Categories issue / error

Tags: 2013, content

Looking for some assistance here.  I have in place a new SharePoint 2013 infrastructure which has been upgraded from SharePoint 2010 (database attach upgrade) with 1 web server and 1 SQL box.

Everything is working perfectly and as expected other than 1 thing.  We are using the community features which have this enabled on all sites.  We are trying to display community content (the categories) from the parent (top level site) to the home page of subsites.  The webpart designed to do this is the "Content Rollup – Cetegories" web part.  However whenever I insert this web part I get

"Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator."

I also get a similar error message when trying to use SharePoint designer (web part zone and adding the same web part).

This is causing me a massive headache – if anyone has any ideas / suggestions – I would be forever grateful.

Happy to post code sample if required

Thanks

Wayne

Comment: You should download the ULS Viewer and see if you can find anything useful in the logs: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer